# BEFORE or INSTEAD OF Insert SQL Server triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a small problem. What I want to achieve is before inserting data to table A, I want to check if this data is in table B and table C.

When tables B and C don't have this data, I'd like to add data from 'inserted' to table B and C (and insert data to table A at the end), but if they have already this row, I don't want to insert anything to table A and B (and don't know to insert anything to table A as well).

Is there any way I can control if the data from inserted will be inserted in table A or not?

Comment: What database server are you using?

Comment: Smells like a bad design. Also, can't you write appropriate `insert-select` statement with couple of `not exists()`?

Comment: I'm using sql server. If in the 'instead of insert' trigger I write 'INSERT INTO tableA SELECT * FROM inserted',will it work or just execute my trigger again?

Comment: How are you controlling the inserts into `Table A`?